# How to submit form which has data that is prepopulate and posted data

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form which has 2 types of inputs, prepopulated and data and data that requires to be added in the input.

I am trying to submit the form but I am getting nothing in the data base. I have found several related answers but they are old and require that either all the data to pre-populated or all data to be added, but in my form it is a mix of both.

Here is the views:

```
def addlog(request, pk):
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = LogForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = Log()  
            data.log_workout = form.cleaned_data['log_workout'] <------ prepopulated in template
            data.log_repetitions = form.cleaned_data['log_repetitions']<------ not prepopulated in template
            data.workout_id = Workout.pk
            data.save()  
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Template:

```
    <form
    class="review-form" action="{% url 'my_gym:addlog' workout.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <input hidden type="text" name="log_workout" value="{{ object.name }}" required id="id_log_workout">
        <input name="log_repetitions" required id="id_log_repetitions">
      </div>
      <button type="submit">
      </button>
    </form>
```

here is log model:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    log_workout = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True, null=True)
    log_repetitions = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)],blank=True, null=True)

class LogForm(forms.Form):
    log_workout =forms.CharField()
    log_repetitions = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = ['log_workout','log_repetitions']
```

a clarification before adding the input forms in the template I used {{ form|crispy }} and when I manually add data it went to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them through the request object. `request.POST.get('log_workout')` the value *should* be posted because it's inside the form tag
**Edit:** this is only for extra fields *not* in `forms.py`

---

###### General Form Debugging Format (reference)

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.POST)

    form = FormToSave(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        print('Valid!')
        form.save()
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        # or 
        print(form.errors.as_data())
```

^ I automatically place these prints when doing a form, and then I delete them when I know everything is working correctly

Comment: it is still not showing any data in the admin

Comment: Two things. #1 put a `print(request.POST)` and a `print(form.is_valid())`  right below `form = LogForm(request.POST)` and make sure the data is getting there. and then, I'm just wondering, why are you manually doing `data = Log()` instead of just `form.save()`?- with .save() you don't have to do any of this (or shouldn't have to)

Comment: thank you for showing how to debug and try to find the error. It is capturing the data but the Form is showing False for valid. This is how I wrote request Post get  `data.log_workout = request.POST.get('log_workout')`

Comment: Well there's a direction!- missing a required field, I presume: `print(form.errors)` will help you narrow it down, you might have to put it after the is_valid call. and I'm an idiot: you can use form.cleaned_data **if** it's actually a field in the `forms.py` I should have read the question better, sorry for leading you astray

Comment: actually your are right I was able to fix the error `print(form.errors)` helped me to narrow it down thank you